# ng-repeat showing custom message for the 1st iteration only

Tags: angularjs

I have below code following sample data

```
$scope.studentPermissions  = [ 
{entities[{StudentName: 'Tester', entityStudents[{FirstName: 'Test0', LastName: 'Test0', userPermissions[{prop 1, prop2, prop3}]}]}]},
{entities[{StudentName: 'Tester', entityStudents[{FirstName: 'Test1', LastName: 'Test2', userPermissions[{prop 1, prop2, prop3}]}]}]},
{entities[{StudentName: 'Tester', entityStudents[{FirstName: 'Test3', LastName: 'Test4', userPermissions[{prop 1, prop2, prop3}]}]}]},
]
```

**Code:**

```
<div>
     <input type="text" ng-model="searchStudent">
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="studentPermissions in studentPermissions">
            <div ng-repeat="student in studentPermissions.entities">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td >Student</td>
                            <td>{{student.StudentName}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th ng-repeat="permission in student.entityStudents[0].userPermissions"><div><span>{{permission.Name}}</span></div></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="student in filteredData =(student.entityStudents | filter:searchStudent)">
                            <td>{{student.FirstName}} {{student.LastName}}</td>
                            <td ng-repeat="permission in student.userPermissions">
                                <input ng-model="permission.Checked" type="checkbox">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div ng-show="!filteredData.length">No matching student found</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Currently, if student is not found then system shows `No data found` message 3 times. In fact message `No matching student found` is showing for each `<div ng-repeat="student in studentPermissions.entities">`..

I want to show it only one.. e.g. if the message is already showing for 1st iteration than don't show it for 2nd iteration.

Any help please.

Comment: Just move it outside the ng-repeat? And do the check for data in your controller and bind it to your element.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz if i move filteredData out from ng-repeat than it is not recognized.. always null. out of scope.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for this? I'd a bit unclear what exactly it is you want.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, isnt there a way that can tell whether  <div ng-show="!filteredData.length">No matching student found</div> has been already executed? does not matter even if looks simple

Comment: You can set a scope variable in your controller to true or false if the message shows up, and then do stuff based off that.

Comment: @ Chrillewoodz, yes but how? i have no idea how to set variable in controller from html .. Appreciate if you can highlight

Comment: Provide a working fiddle and I can show you.

Comment: @ Chrillewoodz, no idea how fiddler will help u in this case... its to complex to write fiddler.. everyone not like u expert. its ok thanks for your tll now .. no more question